# Can anyone tell me why is there so much space in output on andorid device?

Tags: android, user-interface

I have created this file called quicksearch and it is used to search. I an using android studio and i don't know why but in output on nexus 4, there is lot of space in it.

[Here is](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3wHealzmk4JNDFZQk1IMmZQZWs/edit?usp=sharing)  the link to output on my nexus 4. You can see huge empty space in the middle of output. I did try different devices including sony xperia, samsung, still there is no change in the output.

[here is](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3wHealzmk4JWl82UW8xWThwU3c/edit?usp=sharing) the link to output on android studio. You can see there is no space here, still there is space  in the output on the mobile device.

here is my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <View android:id="@+id/fakeView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Unique ID"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="GO"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="94dp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/color1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/color2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fakeView"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/clarity2" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/color2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_below="@+id/shape"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/fakeView"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/clarity1"
            android:layout_above="@+id/cut"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/fakeView" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/clarity2"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/clarity1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/clarity1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/cut"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fakeView"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fakeView"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/cut2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fakeView"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fakeView"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/clarity2" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/shape"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/fakeView" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/shape2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fakeView"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/color1" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Carat :"
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cut"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/from"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/fakeView"
            android:hint="From:"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/to"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/clarity1"
            android:hint="To:"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Select Stones :"
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/from"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
            android:layout_below="@+id/from"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/submit">

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Single"
                android:id="@+id/single"
                android:checked="true" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Twin"
                android:id="@+id/twin"
                android:checked="false" />

        </RadioGroup>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Submit"
            android:id="@+id/submit"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

here is the code to the above xml file

```
public class QuickSearch extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quicksearch);

        Spinner color1=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.color1);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.color1, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        color1.setAdapter(adapter);


        Spinner color2=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.color2);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.color2, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        color2.setAdapter(adapter2);


        Spinner shape=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.shape);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter3 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.shape, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        shape.setAdapter(adapter3);


        Spinner shape2=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.shape2);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter8 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.shape2, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter8.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        shape2.setAdapter(adapter8);



        Spinner clarity1=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.clarity1);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter4 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.clarity1, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter4.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        clarity1.setAdapter(adapter4);



        Spinner clarity2=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.clarity2);
         ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter5 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.clarity2, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter5.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        clarity2.setAdapter(adapter5);


        Spinner cut=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.cut);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter6 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.cut, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter6.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        cut.setAdapter(adapter6);

        Spinner cut2=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.cut2);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter7 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.cut2, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter7.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        cut2.setAdapter(adapter7);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of relative layout, try using nested linear layouts... Relative layouts are known to sometimes cause problems on screens with different densities

Comment: can you please tell me in detail which two layout shall i use??

Comment: Start with vertical linear layout ... in that add horizontal linear layout to hold your edittext and button...then keep adding horizontal layouts to hold your spinners. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22537084/android-layout-with-images-and-compatibility/22542256#22542256) is not the exact answer, but it will give you a basic idea